# Why can I see two numbers by clicking on the up-down vote counter?

Tags: discussion, support

What does this mean when I double clicks in the up-down vote counter..

[image: UpDown]

Comment: It means that you are an [established user](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) on the target site :)

Comment: Ok..I just forgot that...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the ["established user" privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) page:

> ## How do I view vote counts?
>
> Voting scores, as displayed, are the sum of the up and down votes on a post. Vote counts are the individual up and down votes that make up the score.
>
> You can view the vote counts by clicking on the score of a post. This will break the score into upvotes and downvotes, like so:
>
> [image]
>
> The upvotes have a plus sign next to them and are displayed as the top number, in green. The downvotes have a negative sign next to them and are displayed as the bottom number, in red.

Answer (score 7):

This is the post's score details.  The green number is the number of upvotes and the red is the number of downvotes.

The number you see before you click is the total score of the post -

> upvotes - downvotes

You gained the privilege to view this data when you reached [1000 reputation points](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) (on Stack Overflow) and became an established user.

**BTW - You don't need to double click - a single click will suffice :)**

Note - [You can only fetch these vote counts once every second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a5eR.png)